# Laravel htaccess redirects in wrong way

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

Thanks in advance.

I am using laravel 5 and want some fixes in .htaccess file.

Here is my .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The problem is that when i am adding an extra slash after the url it is throwing me at very root of my www folder. Is there any possible solution

http://localhost/project/public/index.php --works fine.
http://localhost/project/public/index.php/ --Redirecting me to http://localhost/index.php

Anyhow i need this redirect to http://localhost/project/public/index.php

Any help appreciated.

Comment: add these line                                                                                                   
    `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but it is still not working.

Now i have edited my .htaccess to

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: try these   `RewriteRule  ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]`

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]` in now redirecting all requests regardless of trailing `/`

Didn't worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally got the perfect solution.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301] // i have replaced the '/' and it worked.
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `config/app.php`, there point the url to your project folder

```
'url' => 'http://localhost',
```

Comment: Done but still same issue.

Comment: Try `RewriteBase /project/public/` after `RewriteEngine On`